# No Folder Creation despite mkdir being called

Tags: java, android, directory

As always, I apologize if this is simplistic, I am a novice with no formal education. I head to Uni in fall of 2018.

I have a password manager which creates a backup of its settings to a file, so the user can restore it at a later time. While I was testing this feature (and the corresponding "Restore" feature) I had it simply put the backup file in the user's download directory. There were no issues with this, and I must say ***there are no issues with permissions***. Runtime and manifest permissions are both present and functional.

The issue arose when I sought to have the backup file put in a directory of my own making. I wanted it to be put in a folder called "PSync" in the user's Documents directory. The code to check if it exists and if not then to create it runs correctly, and no errors are called. It simply does nothing. Attached is the relevant code, and a picture demonstrating the path it uses. It should be noted that the statements inside the `} else {` run but the file is not created.

```
 String dirPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath().toString();
                    dirPath = dirPath + "/PSync";
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Path: " + dirPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    File directory = new File(dirPath);

                    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
                    } else {
                        directory.mkdir();
                        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Directory created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Pic with demonstrated file path:

[image]

Comment: Please explain **exactly** how you are determining that it "does nothing". Are you using `adb shell`? Are you using an on-device file manager? Are you using a file manager on your development machine? Are you using something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare I apologize, I should have been more clear. Despite the call, the folder is never created. I'm mainly checking this by using the file manager on the device (it shows hidden folders). The application also always evaluates  if (directory.isDirectory()) { as false. Log cat doesn't seem to show anything relevant, but I could be missing something. No errors, at least.

Comment: I suggest verifying that the name of the directory you are trying to create is what you think it is.  Note also that `File.mkdir()` is not documented to throw an exception if it fails, except in the case that an installed `SecurityManager` blocks it.  If it fails in another way or for some other reason then you should expect it to notify you by returning `false`.  Which you do not presently check for.

Comment: I'll add something to check if it's false. As for the directory...I believe I already have? As shown in the picture it shows the proper path. I want the directory to be named "PSync" and to be created inside the documents folder of the user's device. Unless I'm mistaken, that would be the proper path/name. @JohnBollinger

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to create a file path. Create yours using `new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "PSync")`. Also, use `mkdirs()`, in case the device does not have the documents directory yet (that will be the case with some emulator images). And, do not use `Toast` for diagnostics, as you can get tripped up by word-wrap and stuff. Use `Log` to put your own messages in LogCat.

Comment: Made suggested edits, JohnBollinger and @CommonsWare. Still does not create the folder. Didn't see a log message either, so I think I did that wrong. I'll try to fix that, didn't use debugger until yesterday. Processor doesn't support VD, so had to set up my phone for it once I had a proper phone. Before then used toasts and made do.

Comment: You should use File.exists() to check existence. And your toast cries succes even when mkdirs() fails. You forgot the -runtime- permissins i think.:

Comment: Didn't forget it, toasts are removed, and why file exists when I already have dir exists? Regardless, the problem was resolved, I'll add an answer when I get back to my desktop.

Comment: ???  I dont see you using .exists().

Comment: Apologies, I'm on my phone. directory.isDirectory() is what checks for the existence of the directly. Returns false if the folder doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved due to comments, primarily by CommonsWare. I believe the exact fix was using `File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environme‌​nt.DIRECTORY_DOCUMEN‌​TS), "PSync")`, the rest is simply reflects good programming practices such as error checking.

The new code is;

```
 //Checks if the specified directory exists.
                    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "PSync");

                    //Saves this path to be used later.
                    String bkPath = directory.getPath().toString();

                    //Checks if the directory exists. If it does not, then it creates it.
                    if (directory.exists()) {
                    } else {
                        Boolean success = directory.mkdirs();
                        if (success) {
                          Log.e(directory.getPath(), "Directory successfully created");
                        } else {
                            Log.e(directory.getPath(), "Directory creation failed.");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Apparently I cannot accept this for two days. The issue is resolved, but I welcome any additional advice.